# Editing Date in Dataframe to show Year in pandas

Tags: python, date, pandas, merge, panel-data

I've got 2 datapanels loaded as df's in pandas :

**df1:**

[image]

**df2:**

[image]

Both of them have the same Years/Countries, but the first one has the year entries in mm/dd/yy format while the second one has only years. I need to merge them, which shouldn't be too hard, but I don't know how to reformat the date in the first one so it specifies years and not dates.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to splice in the century explicitly (to avoid it being parsed as 20XX):

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([["12/31/50", "Argentina"], ["12/31/51", "Argentina"], ["12/31/52", "Argentina"]], columns=["Year", "Country"])

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
       Year    Country
0  12/31/50  Argentina
1  12/31/51  Argentina
2  12/31/52  Argentina
```

without splicing:

```
In [13]: pd.to_datetime(df["Year"])
Out[13]:
0   2050-12-31
1   2051-12-31
2   2052-12-31
Name: Year, dtype: datetime64[ns]

In [14]: pd.to_datetime(df["Year"], format="%m/%d/%y")
Out[14]:
0   2050-12-31
1   2051-12-31
2   2052-12-31
Name: Year, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

with splicing:

```
In [15]: df["Year"].apply(lambda s: s[:-2] + "19" + s[-2:])
Out[15]:
0    12/31/1950
1    12/31/1951
2    12/31/1952
Name: Year, dtype: object

In [16]: pd.to_datetime(df["Year"].apply(lambda s: s[:-2] + "19" + s[-2:]), format="%m/%d/%Y")
Out[16]:
0   1950-12-31
1   1951-12-31
2   1952-12-31
Name: Year, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Note: You could try the parsing in the apply (which *may* be more efficient).

---

You can pull out the year from a datetime Series with the .dt accessor:

```
In [21]: df["Year"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Year"].apply(lambda s: s[:-2] + "19" + s[-2:]), format="%m/%d/%Y")

In [22]: df["Year"].dt.year
Out[22]:
0    1950
1    1951
2    1952
Name: Year, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can achieve what you wish in least amount of code:

```
df['Year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Year']).dt.year - 100
```

however bear in mind that changing the date to just 'year' will also change the column dtype to int

```
>>> df.dtypes
Year        int64
Country    object
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

`educ['Year'] = educ['Year'].year` should get you the year in the data frame, provided the frame contains a date, if not you can convert them using the [to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) function, as follows:

```
educ['Year'] = [y - 100 for y in pd.to_datetime(edu['Year'], infer_datetime_format=True).year]
```

Comment: It does infer the date correctly, but appending .year yields an error:
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'year'

Comment: It actually infers it incorrectly, changing 1950-1965 to 2050-2065

Comment: That should sort you